# Get a count of currently active users from Google RealTime API (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get a count of the number of people currently viewing my site.  With Google Analytics about to switch over to GA4 from UA, I figure it's best to use GA4 but the documentation--especially for the API--is pretty weak.  I believe I need to query the Realtime API but I'm having trouble putting together the request to do it.  Right now I'm stuck on the authorization step, but I'm not really sure any of it makes sense in the first place.  I've created a service account in Google Analytics.

Here's what I have at the moment, cobbled together from a variety of sources, currently giving me a 401 error:

```js
<div id="active-users"></div>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{SERVICE_CLIENT_ID}.apps.googleusercontent.com">

<script>
  // Load the Google Analytics API client library
  gapi.load('client', function () {
    gapi.client.init({
      client_id: '{SERVICE_CLIENT_ID}',
      apiKey: '{API_KEY}'
    }).then(function () {
      gapi.client.request({
        path: '/v1/data/realtime:get',
        params: {
          ids: 'GA4:{PROPERTY_ID}',
          metrics: 'rt:activeUsers'
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
        var activeUsers = response.result.totalsForAllResults['rt:activeUsers'];
        document.getElementById('active-users').innerHTML = 'Active users: ' + activeUsers;
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

EDIT:
I am trying to follow [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-basics), which seems relevant, but I can't find any information on how to translate this to the Client Library

Comment: are you trying to use the sign-in library with the data api?  Is that even documented as possible?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I just want to show the number.  The documentation is very confusing, but it seemed to imply that a service client could be given auth credentials and do this.  Maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example: https://polydactyl-plain-seatbelt.glitch.me/

Some notes:

1. Details about [the realtime API method itself](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runRealtimeReport)
2. Details about [Google JS API client](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client)
3. It's impossible to use Service Accounts authorisation with JS API client due to it's public code source. Instead [you need to create OAuth Client ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js#create_credentials).

Comment: This seems to match my research, unfortunately:  can I confirm that the only way for a website to show these figures is to have each end user log in?  That seems dumb, but it's what I found too.

Comment: Yeah, you need some server side code to show this figure publicly. E.g. use cloud functions or Apps Script.

Answer (score -1):

From what i can understand, you are facing API authentication error.
Assuming you've created google cloud console, enable google analytic API for your project etc.

Try the following authentication method:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { BetaAnalyticsData } = require('@google-analytics/data');
const keyPath = 'service_account_key.json';

// Authenticate using the private key
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: keyPath,
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'],
});

// Create a client object
const client = new BetaAnalyticsData({
  auth: auth,
});

// Make API requests using the client object
const request = {
  property: 'properties/<YOUR-PROPERTY-ID>',
  metrics: [
    {
      name: 'activeUsers',
    },
  ],
};
client.runRealtimeReport({ request }).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

You can get more information from its [documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client).

The example you've provided could be written considering Realtime API.

```
const { BetaAnalyticsDataClient } = require('@google-analytics/data');
const keyPath = '/path/to/service_account_key.json';

// Authenticate using the private key
const client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient({
  credentials: {
    keyFilePath: keyPath,
  },
});

// Make API requests using the client object
const request = {
  property: 'properties/<YOUR-PROPERTY-ID>',
  metrics: [
    {
      name: 'activeUsers',
    },
  ],
};
client.runRealtimeReport({ request }).then((response) => {
  const activeUsers = response.data.totals[0].values[0];
  document.getElementById('active-users').innerHTML = 'Active users: ' + activeUsers;
});
```